# How to move macros from one user login to another?

Tags: vba, excel

[image]

I have previously made macros file and trying to move to other user id.
However when i am clicking macros options in the same excel file from other user id i am unable to see personal.xlsb.
Can anyone please guide step by step how to implement (copy/paste) macros?

Comment: Create a macro on the users PC and select "Store Macro in"  and "Personal Macro Workbook". This will create the hidden workbook that you can then import macros to

Comment: If you are to let others has every single personal macro you have, search in Explorer for **personal.xlsb** in your user profile, then copy paste this file (with excel closed) to similar path on other user's profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to save the original file as macro-enabled (.xlsm),  not default (.xlsx). The other user will have an option to enable macros after opening macros.

You can also consider using macro-enabled template file (.xltm).

Since macros can be designed to damage system (like virus), it makes sense not to allow them in the default file format.